# Custom ID generator and saving to file

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I'm having trouble using BufferedReader. I was able to make this on Python, but Java is very confusing to me. BTW this is an Activity on Android Studio. The ultimate plan is to calculate the length from the given values and keep track of the length as the roll gets used, however, I'm not sure if there is a more effective way of saving data other than using text files. If so, please tell.

Things I have:

rollID.txt, rollType.txt, rollWidth.txt, rollWeight.txt, rollLenght.txt and obviously addRoll.java

Logic:

1. When add Roll Activity is opened it should search rollID.txt for the latest roll # (0001, 0002, ...., 0124... and so on...) and add 1 more and display it to the TextView at the top (currently marked 0001). If the file is empty it should start with "0001".
2. When the Roll is officially added using the add button it should save the generated Roll ID on the next line of rollID.txt. It should save the 309 or 321 option to rollType.txt and from the spinner, it should save to rollWidth.txt and finally the weight saving to rollWeight.txt. They should be on corresponding lines in each text file.
3. Using the data provided by the user it will calculate the length of the roll using width, thickness, density, and weight and save that value to rollLength.txt

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_roll);
       TextView rollId = findViewById(R.id.rollid);
   }
   ```

I apologize if this is very confusing, but I'm happy to answer any questions you have about the app.

This is what the Activity looks like:

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

> This will a java console based program where You will get the next
>   rollnumber and based on the other input input will be written to files
>   accordingly, Let me know if this is what you wanted. P.S this works
>   for java 7 and above

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static int lineNumber = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File rootFolder = new File("C:\\Test");//Location for all Text files

            //Get nextId (default 001)
            int rolNumber = getDataFromRollIDTxt();
            lineNumber = rolNumber-1;
            String rollNumber = String.format("%04d",rolNumber); //Adding leading zeros
            System.out.println("Next generated RollNumber %03d :: "+rollNumber);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            //For RollType
            System.out.print("Enter your RollType (309/321):: ");       
            String type = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(type);

            //For RollWidth
            System.out.print("Enter your rollWidth:: ");
            String width = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(width);

            //For RollWeight
            System.out.print("Enter your rollWeight:: ");
            String weight = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(weight);

            //Saving Data to respective files at corresponding lineNumbers
            for (File file : rootFolder.listFiles()) {
                Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
                List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("ID")) {
                    lines.add(lineNumber, rollNumber);
                } else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("Weight")) {
                    lines.add(lineNumber, weight);
                } else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("Type")) {
                    lines.add(lineNumber, type);
                } else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("Width")) {
                    lines.add(lineNumber, width);
                } else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("Height")) {
                    long height = Integer.parseInt(width)/Integer.parseInt(weight)+Integer.parseInt(type); //Random calcultaions
                    lines.add(lineNumber, height+"");
                }
                Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }           

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Integer getDataFromRollIDTxt() throws IOException {
        String text = ""; 
        try { 
            text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Test\\rollId.txt")));
            if(!text.isEmpty()) {
                String[] arr = text.split("[\\r\\n]+"); //To get all rollnumbers in Array           
                Integer lastId = Integer.parseInt(arr[arr.length-1]);
                return ++lastId;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }           
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```